# $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) not working with tomcat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I am trying to remove "#" from the URL of my Angular JS app. It is currently deployed on tomcat server on my location machine and accessible through a custom port like :8081.

I looked at various articles and also different threads on stackoverflow to fix the issue. But all went in vain.

I am getting following error (from developer console of the browser) when I try to access the home page of my app using `localhost:8081/myAngularApp`.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myAngularApp due to:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'html5Mode' of undefined
    at http://localhost:8081/myAngularApp/js/angularMyApp.js:34:31
    .....
    .....
```

If I remove `$locationProvider.html5Mode({...});` then I am able to access the application with a hash like `http://localhost:8081/myAngularApp/#/`

Here is the snippet from my JS file which configures Angular Module (myAppMain.js) :

```
...
...
myAngularApp.config([ '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
        function($routeProvider, $routeParams, $locationProvider) {

            $routeProvider

            // route for the login page
            .when('/login', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/login.html',
                controller : 'loginController'
            })

            // route for the dashboard page
            .when('/dashboard', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/dashboard.html',
                controller : 'dashboardController'
            });

            // route for the FAQ page
            .when('/faq', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/faq.html',
                controller : 'faqController'
            })

            // route for the About us page
            .when('/aboutUs', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/aboutUs.html',
                controller : 'aboutUsController'
            });

            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'
            });

            if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
                $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                         enabled: true,
                         requireBase: false
                });
            }
        }
    ]);

...
...
```

I have already added `base href="/"` tag in the head tag of `index.html`.

I am not sure if I have to do some changes at tomcat end to make it working or there is some other problem..

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
myAngularApp.config([ '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $routeParams, $locationProvider) {
```

should be

```
myAngularApp.config([ '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,  $locationProvider) {
```

Comment: It did not work. After making about changes I get following error :

Comment: angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myAngularApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeParams
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeParams

Comment: Remove routeParams, check updated answer, as it is not used in config, you might require it in controller